# Rails Namespace Controller Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, routes, content-management-system, namespaces

I've split my rails app into a admin directory and a public directory.

The admin directory is within an Admin:: namespace (/admin).

When I created a controller called Forums in both the Admin:: namespace and the normal root map area, the routing seems to find the Admin::Forums controller for /forums and /admin/forums.

So /admin/forums => "app/controllers/admin/forums_controller.rb"
So /forums => "app/controllers/admin/forums_controller.rb"

Not sure why this is happening, are the root controllers somehow inherited amoung both controllers? When I try to execute code within the non-admin forums controller, nothing gets exercuted.

Here is my route:

```
  map.resources :forums, :only => [:index,:show] do |forum|
    forum.resources :topics, :shallow => true, :only => [:index,:show], :name_prefix => ""
  end

  map.namespace :admin, :name_prefix => "", :path_prefix => "/admin", :name_prefix => "admin_" do |admin|

    admin.resources :forums, :name_prefix => 'admin_' do |forum|
      forum.resources :topics, :name_prefix => 'admin_' do |topic|
        topic.resources :posts, :name_prefix => 'admin_'
      end
    end

   end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it's a little duplicate from your other questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146659/rails-2-namespace-and-shallow-routes-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify the name_prefix twice for the main admin namespace call (which is going to essentially choose one option at random).  Also you don't need the name_prefix option in the sub resources.  Here's mine from my app - some of the sub resources in the namespace (questions and users) are also main resources and there's no confusion.

```
  map.namespace :admin do |admin| 
    admin.resources :home, :only => [:index]
    admin.resources :questions, :collection => {:edit_by_text => :get, :update_by_text => :post, :import_progress => :post}
    admin.resources :users
    admin.resources :subjects, :member => {:make_quizzes => :post}
  end
```